# Display SweetAlert popup if a Div Class does NOT exist on the page

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to display a SweetAlert popup if a div class is NOT on the page, it seems to work with ID but not with classes.

Can anyone help this popup display if a div class is not present on the page?

```
<div class="box">
    <img id="mainimage" src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8

WORKING (we have an ID called mainimage and the popup doesn't display. When I change to mainimages it shows the popup as it should)

```
if (!document.getElementById("mainimage")) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Rick Astley',
        html: '<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
    });
};
```

When I try to check whether the excluded class name (carrd) is present, it doesn't seem to work or if it is changed to a div on the page

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName("carrd")) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Rick Astley',
        html: '<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
    });
};
```

Comment: The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object, so you may need to check the length is greater than 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the length property from the result of that function.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("carrd").length === 0) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Rick Astley',
        html: '<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
    });
};
```

Explanation: *getElementsByClassName* always returns an HTML collection, and therefore it won't work in the way you expect it with the *!* operator

It works with the *getElementById* function because that returns a found element, or *null* if no elements are found.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("carrd")
```

returns array of elements having that carrd class.
Go with below code.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("carrd").length === 0)
```